# Time Complexity: 3Sum algorithm under cubic time?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search

How can I make use of **binary search** for improving my algorithms time complexity?

I'm reviewing time complexity for some interviews & I'm having trouble making my algorithm more time efficient. This is my brute force solution for the 3-Sum problem: how many triples sum to exactly 0? Background: I don't have a CS degree.

```
//BRUTE FORCE SOLUTION: N^3
var threeSum = function(list){
  var count = 0;

  //checking each triple
  for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    for(var j = i+1; j < list.length; j++){
      for(var k = j+1; k < list.length; k++){

        if(list[i] + list[j] + list[k] === 0){count++;}
      }
    }
  }
  return count;
};

//binary search code
var binarySearch = function(target, array){
  var lo  = 0;
  var hi  = array.length - 1;
  //base case
  while(lo <= hi){
    var mid = Math.floor( lo + (hi - lo) / 2 );
    if(target === array[mid]) return mid;
    if(target < array[mid]){
      hi = mid - 1;
    }
    if(target > array[mid]){
      lo = mid + 1;
    }
  }
  // value not found
  return -1;
}
```

I was reviewing an algorithms course online from Princeton & the professor noted that this algorithm could be made more efficient with use of a binary search algorithm.

According to the professor we would:

- sort the list
- for each pair of numbers array[ i ] & array[ j ] binary search for -(array[ i ] + array[ j ])

However, I'm having trouble understanding how binary search comes in to solve the problem. Here is a slide from the lecture, which I'm still trying to understand, but maybe useful to others:

[image]

I'm sure there a several efficient solutions out there: feel free to chime in with your implementation as it may help me and other future readers. Thanks

Comment: The condition `list[i] + list[j] + list[k] === 0` is equivalent (more or less) to `list[k] === -(list[i] + list[j])`, which makes the `k` loop of the brute-force solution a linear search, to be replaced by binary search.

Answer (score 4):

> However, I'm having trouble understanding how binary search comes in to solve the problem.

This is how the n^2 log(n) algorithm works:

1. Sort the list in O(nlogn) time
2. Find all pairs of numbers `(i,j)`, which is O(n^2) runtime.
3. Then, for each pair (i,j), it finds a number `k` where `k = sum - j - i`. This is constant time O(1)
4. The algorithm checks to see if each `k` exists, since the tuple `(i,j,k)` would sum to `sum`. To do this, do a **binary search** which takes log(n) time.

The final runtime would be O(nlogn) + O(logn * n^2) = O(n^2logn)

An alternative (and faster) solution would be to replace the sorting portion with a hashtable. Then, lookup of value `k` would take O(1) time instead of logn

Comment: Is your hashtable  solution still valid if the array contains duplications? IE:[-1,-1,0]

Answer (score 1):

The problem that the binary search approach is trying to solve is reducing the complexity of a cubic algorithm (this is your brute force algorithm) into a ~ N^2 log N algorithm.

As other commenters pointed out we know that when the following statement: `list[i] + list[j] + list[k] == 0` is `true` than we found a 3SUM result. This is the same as saying that `-(list[i] + list[j]) == list[k]`. So the goal of the algorithm is to check for each `i` index and `j` index pair that there is a corresponding `k` index which satisfies the previous equation. Binary search can find those `k` indices in ~log N time. Hence the overall order of growth being ~N^2 log N (the outer for loops correspond to the N^2 part).

As for the implementation in javascript I would do it like this:

```js
var threesum = function(list) {
  list.sort(function(a,b){return a - b});
  console.log(list);
  var cnt = 0;
  for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    for(var j=i+1; j<list.length; j++) {
      var k = bsearch(-(list[i]+list[j]), list);
      if (k!= null && k > j) {
        console.log("[i=%d], [j=%d], [k=%d]", i,j,k);
        cnt++;
      }
    }
  }
  return cnt;
};

var bsearch = function(key, a) {
  var lo = 0;
  var hi = a.length-1;
  while (lo <= hi) {
    var mid = lo + Math.floor((hi - lo) / 2);
    if (a[mid] < key) {
      lo = mid + 1;
    } else if (a[mid] > key) {
      hi = mid - 1;
    } else {
      return mid;
    }
  }
  return null;
};

threesum([41, 48, 31, 32, 34, 38, 1, -9, 12, 13, 99, 5, -65, 8, 3, -3])
```

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm basically works in the following way:

- Sort the array (worst-case `O(n ^ 2)`, depending upon sorting algorithm)
- Generate all pairs of numbers - takes `O(n ^ 2)`
- for each pair `(i , j)`, there might exist `k`, such that 0 = i + j + k`.`k`is simply`-(i + j)`, thus we can easily look it up by binary search in`O(log n)`. Cases where`i < k < j` doesn't hold are avoided to exclude duplicates.

Thus total time-complexity is `O(n ^ 2 log n)`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const threeSum =(array,target)=>{
  
  let result =[]
  
   array = array.sort((a,b)=> a-b)
  
  for(let i=0; i < array.length-2; i++){
    
    let left = i+1;
    let right = array.length -1;
    
    while(left < right){
      
      let sum = array[i]+ array[left]+ array[right];
      
      if(sum === target){
        result.push([array[i],array[left], array[right]]);
        
        left++;
        right--
      }else if(sum < target){
        
        //sum is lower than target so increment left pointer 
        left++;
      }else if(sum > target){
        //sum is greater than target so increment right pointer 
        right--;
      }
    }
    
    
  }
  //return the list 
  return result;
}

let a = [12, 3, 1, 2, -6, 5, -8, 6];
console.log(threeSum(a, 0));
```

```
  Time Complexity: O(n^2) 
  Space Complexity: O(1)
```